# In QTP, is there any possiblitiy to come out of calling function based on the result from called function

Tags: vba, vbscript, qtp

I am calling a function arithmetic from my action and the function is being executed. From that function I'm calling another function for manipulating exact data. Here if I were getting a error means I don't want to execute the rest of the code in function1. I have tried using on error resume next in both functions, in function1 alone, function2 alone  but it has not worked out for the scenario. Here is a sample code . This will be called from my action. Also I don't like to pass a variable from function2 each and every time to validate the err.number and to proceed the steps in function1

```
Function arithmetic()

Call div (21,0)

Call add (21,0)

Call sub(21,0)

End function

Function div(a,b)

A=a/b

End function
```

In this case I'll get a error . So i don't want the rest of the code to be executed in function lik function add and sub. Directly I have to return to action and another set of data has to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

To implement decent VBScript error handling for a sequence of dependend actions that shouldn't proceed in case, follow the rules:

1. Put the sequence of actions into a Sub/Function
2. Call this Sub/Function in a OERN
3. Just one risky line in OERN scope

Demo for a script that reads, calc/save, and zap (old) data:

```
Option Explicit

Dim iRet
Dim aErr
On Error Resume Next  ' disable while development to see error line
  iRet = main() ' just *one* risky line in OERN scope
  aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)
On Error GoTo 0
If 0 <> aErr(0) Then
   WScript.Echo "fatal error", aErr(0), "-", aErr(1), "in", aErr(2)
   iRet = 1
Else
   WScript.Echo "success"
End If
WScript.Quit iRet

Function main()
  main = 2
  ReadData
  CalcAndSave
  ZapOld
  main = 0
End Function

Sub ReadData()
  If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("read") Then Err.Raise 123, "ReadData()", "can't read"
  WScript.Echo "reading data"
End Sub

Sub CalcAndSave()
  If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("calc") Then Err.Raise 124, "CalcAndSave()", "can't calc and save"
  WScript.Echo "calc and save data"
End Sub

Sub ZapOld()
  If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("zap") Then Err.Raise 125, "ZapOld()", "can't zap"
  WScript.Echo "zap old data"
  If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("surprise") Then
     Dim i : i = 1 / 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Call it like

```
cscript 25309137.vbs /calc
reading data
fatal error 124 - can't calc and save in CalcAndSave()
```

Disable the **one and only strictly local** OERN to be sure you are not hiding any errors and to get line number info while developing:

```
cscript 25309137.vbs /surprise
reading data
calc and save data
zap old data
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\25301708\vbs\25309137.vbs(39, 14) Microsoft VBScript runtime er
o
```

In your case, the risky sequence is done in a loop. According to the rule, demo code should look like:

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Quit main()

Function main()
  Dim aErr, n
  For Each n In Array(1, 2, 0, 4)
    On Error Resume Next  ' disable while development to see error line
      arithmetic n ' just *one* risky line in OERN scope
      aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If 0 <> aErr(0) Then
       WScript.Echo "fatal error", aErr(0), "-", aErr(1), "in", aErr(2)
    End If
  Next
  main = 0
End Function

Sub arithmetic(n)
  divide n
  add    n
  mult   n
End Sub

Sub divide(n)
  WScript.Echo n, 1 / n
End Sub

Sub add(n)
  WScript.Echo n, 1 + n
End Sub

Sub mult(n)
  WScript.Echo n, 1 * n
End Sub
```

output:

```
cscript 25309137-2.vbs
1 1
1 2
1 1
2 0,5
2 3
2 2
fatal error 11 - Division by zero in Microsoft VBScript runtime error
4 0,25
4 5
4 4
```